# Pulling data with 'Where' and 'Include' statements at the same time

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have managed to get my include statements working with my foreign keys however when I try to add a 'where' statement to the findAll statement I am getting the below error. I have checked my foreign keys and models numerous times and I can't see any problems with them.

Do I have the syntax correct in the below API? The data in the keys is important so I don't want to have to spend more time on a workaround. I have seen other examples that have the where statement inside one of the include keys but the fields I want pulled are on the main table so I don't think this is the same situation.

> Unhandled rejection Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.

API

```
const sequelize = require("pg");
const { Sequelize, Op, Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

exports.schoolDiveLogApproval = (req, res) => {

    try {
        const schoolID = req.params.schoolID;

        diveLog.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: diveType, as: 'diveTypeID_FK2',
            }, {
                model: diveSchool, as: 'diveSchoolID_FK',
            }, {
                model: current, as: 'currentID_FK',
            }, {
                model: visibility, as: 'visibilityID_FK',
            }, {
                model: user, as: 'userID_FK1',
            }, {
                model: diveSpot, as: 'diveSpotID_FK2'
            }],
            where: {
                [Op.and]: [
                    {diveSchoolID: schoolID},
                    {diveVerifiedBySchool: false}
                ]
            },
        })

...........
```

**Update**

Error message

```
{
    "message": "missing FROM-clause entry for table \"diveLog\""
}
```

Controller API with raw SQL

```
exports.schoolDiveLogApproval = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const schoolID = req.params.schoolID;
        const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');
        await diveLog.sequelize.query(
            'SELECT * '+
            'FROM "diveLogs" '+
            'LEFT OUTER JOIN "diveTypes" AS "diveTypeID_FK2" ON "diveLogs"."diveTypeID" = "diveTypeID_FK2"."diveTypeID" ' +
            'LEFT OUTER JOIN "diveSchools" AS "diveSchoolID_FK" ON "diveLog"."diveSchoolID" = "diveSchoolID_FK"."diveSchoolID" ' +
            'LEFT OUTER JOIN "currents" AS "currentID_FK" ON "diveLog"."currentID" = "currentID_FK"."currentID" ' +
            'LEFT OUTER JOIN "visibilities" AS "visibilityID_FK" ON "diveLog"."visibilityID" = "visibilityID_FK"."visibilityID" ' +
            'LEFT OUTER JOIN "userLogins" AS "userID_FK" ON "diveLog"."userID" = "userID_FK1"."userID" ' +
            'LEFT OUTER JOIN "diveSpots" AS "diveSpotID_FK2" ON "diveLog"."diveSpotID" = "diveSpotFK2"."diveSpotID" ' +
            'WHERE "diveLogs"."diveSchoolID" = ? ' +
            'AND "diveLogs"."diveVerifiedBySchool" = ?',
            {
                replacements: [schoolID, false],
                type: QueryTypes.SELECT
            }
        )
```

All the table and column names look correct as per the pgAdmin database so I can't see where the problem could be other than the syntax.

I have went off the way the SQL is executed in the IDE terminal so it should execute in theory. Is this more likely be to do with the way I pass the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I went back to using the original Sequelize with the include / where clauses I removed the [Op and] from the API, then re-declared each of the models at the top of the file and it worked.

```
exports.schoolDiveLogApproval = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const schoolID = req.params.schoolID;
        diveLog.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: diveType, as: 'diveTypeID_FK2',
            }, {
                model: diveSchool, as: 'diveSchoolID_FK',
            }, {
                model: current, as: 'currentID_FK',
            }, {
                model: visibility, as: 'visibilityID_FK',
            }, {
                model: user, as: 'userID_FK1',
            }, {
                model: diveSpot, as: 'diveSpotID_FK2'
            }],
            where: [{
                    diveSchoolID: req.params.schoolID,
                    diveVerifiedBySchool: false
            }],
        })
            .then((diveLog) => {
                const schoolDiveLogList = [];
                for (i = 0; i < diveLog.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've really tried some minutes around this sequelize, but I'd really suggest you to learn and use raw SQL, its way easier and universal than that.

After half an hour of trying to set up and understand this sqlize and see so many weird issues like these:
[image]

selecting non-existing columns like id, adding an "s" out of nowhere to the name of the table "user_infoS(?)".. so I gave up and came up with a query that might help you, if I understood your problem correctly.

If you send proper schema I can help you further, but yeah, sorry I can't spend more time in this sequelize, this thing is atrocious.

```
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');
await sequelize.query(
  'SELECT *'+ 
  'FROM diveLog l'+
  'JOIN diveType t ON l.diveTypeId = t.id'+
  'JOIN diveSchool s ON l.diveSchoolId = s.id'+
  'JOIN current c ON l.currentId = c.id'+
  'JOIN visibility v ON l.visibilityId = v.id'+
  'JOIN user u ON l.userId = u.id'+
  'JOIN diveSpot sp ON l.diveSpotId = sp.id'+
  'WHERE diveSchoolID = ?'+
    'AND diveVerifiedBySchool = ?',
  {
    replacements: [schoolID, false],
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos, I have added the raw SQL and the model schema for the table I am querying. Are the single letter and id's the name of the joins? I already have the FK's declared in my server file so I am not sure if that is what is causing the statement that seems to be names correctly as per the pg table names to not recognise certain tables.

Comment: The single letters are the aliases for the tables, you can replace it by `JOIN table_name_b ON table_name_a.id = table_name_b.equivalent_id` but its hard to humanly read and write that.
So use aliases.

Comment: Its really hard for me to guess how it would be your query without knowing these table's schemata, you can contact me at marcosdefina@gmail.com if you don't feel comfortable by posting it here.
But this query was only pseudocode, you would need to figure it out the correct column names to use ON joining keys.

Comment: All my table and column names are correct as I have checked numerous times. When I go off other queries the LEFT OUTER JOIN is automatically used by Sequelize so I have included it instead. I am having a problem with a FROM-clause error now.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the first error in your API, ensure you are requiring your models  like below:

```
const { diveLog, diveType, diveSchool, diveSchool, current, visibility, user, diveSpot } = require('../models');
```

The second error message:

{
"message": "relation "divelogs" does not exist"
}

Indicates that the table "divelogs" cannot be found in your database, double check if the table exists, if it does not exist, run your migrations to create the table. Please note that, if enabled Sequelize will automatically make your table names plural. If you define a model called **User**, Sequelize will create the table as **Users**

Answer (score 0):

Second error: you are committing a typo on aliases using sometimes "devLogS" and other times "devLoG" (in the singular).

Try more before asking here, we won't do your work for you.